# Why is the body of the rocket so long and does it effect the flight?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics, rocket-science

so my qustion is that why are rockets body so fricken long it is crazy all the rockets body are so very long and I need an answer to the question please tell me it is for science and i really need help

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are long because that shape is more aerodynamically efficient. The atmospheric drag is a big obstacle to rocket launches. The drag is dependent on the surface cross-sectional area in the direction of motion. Having a long cylinder reduces the drag but allows a volume large enough to carry the massive amount of fuel needed. More fuel can be stored by making rocket longer and it won't increase the drag. ts hard to think of a stable volume where the area is so great yet cross-sectional area is so small. See simple drawing below. The shape doesn't effect the flight very much once its above the atmosphere ( ~ 100 km altitude) but it has a great effect on getting it to that altitude.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think it has to do with balance. For example, balance a pencil in the palm of your hand vs balancing a shovel in the palm of your hand. So they are longer because if they start leaning it gives more time for the rocket to rebalance and also it stores more fuel.